# When I change the accepted answer to my question, does the other user lose the 15 points?

Tags: discussion

My question is simple, and I don't believe I have to explain it further here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they will lose the points.  Otherwise you could give unlimited points to various users by changing the accepted answer.

Comment: It should be noted that sometimes the point change doesn't get recorded immediately (a lot of information is statically cached on SE), however there are periodic rep-recalc jobs that run to correct such things. If you ever find that your rep has changed "unexpectedly" and without any visible cause, that is often the reason.